# Determine whether the improper integral $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^2}{1+x^4}\,dx$ exists

Tags: calculus, integration

While doing an exercise I need to prove that $\frac{x^2}{1+x^4}$ is integrable.

So I have to see if $\int_{0}^{\infty} |\frac{x^2}{1+x^4}| dx < \infty$. I tried to divide it in two integrals but I don't know how to continue...

$\int_{0}^{\infty} |\frac{x^2}{1+x^4}| dx = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^2}{1+x^4} dx =\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^2}{1+x^4} dx + \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{x^2}{1+x^4} dx \leq \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1} \frac{2x}{1+(x^2)^2} dx + \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{x^2}{1+x^4} dx$

So the first integral is the arcotangent and it is finite but the second one?

I don't know if that's the best way to do this...

Could anyone help me please?

Comment: The integrand is bounded above by $1/x^2$.

Comment: you're right @DavidMitra thanks!

Comment: Even better, see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1565208/finding-int-infty-infty-fracx2x41-dx?noredirect=1). $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{x^2}{1+x^4} dx =\frac{1}{4} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{y^{-1/4}}{1+y} dy  = \frac{1}{2} \int_0^\infty \frac{y^{-1/4}}{1+y}dy=\frac{1}{2} \frac{\pi}{\sin \frac{3\pi}{4}}=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}}.$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In $[1,\infty)$,$$\frac{x^2}{1+x^4}<\frac{x^2}{x^4}=\frac1{x^2},$$and$$\int_1^\infty\frac1{x^2}\,\mathrm dx=1.$$